# How can I rename many files at once?

Tags: software-recommendation, files, batch-rename

I need to rename a bunch of files in order to fix their sort order, therefore I need to be able to do a sort of "find and replace" so I can replace chunks of the filenames at a time.

What tools should I use? I prefer GUI but a command line tool recommendation would also be fine.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

There are a few but I recommend [gprename](http://packages.ubuntu.com/gprename) [image: Install gprename]
 which is a good compromise between usability and functionality.

Other tools are: rename, [krename](http://packages.ubuntu.com/krename) [image: Install krename]
, [pyrenamer](http://packages.ubuntu.com/pyrenamer) [image: Install pyrenamer]
, cuteRenamer, ...

Comment: pyRenamer is not bad at all.

Comment: I have use pyrenamer often and sometimes gprename unless the change is very easily done on the command line.   The best thing about these GUI's is the built-in 'preview' action.  This will save you headaches.

Comment: +1 for gprename, just tried and done the needed rename in 5 seconds

Comment: Shame neither gprename or pyrename can take list of files to rename from the command line

Comment: gprename is great on 14.04. Did 300 folders renaming by regex in 15 seconds

Comment: Another +1 from me for pyrenamer, I'm a big fan.

Answer (score 10):

I really like **qmv** from the `renameutils` package. It enables you to use your favorite (terminal based) text editor to rename files. I prefer to invoke it with `-f do` which gives you a single column (one row per file) with filenames. Combined with the power of Vim it gives you all the tools you need to do massive filename editing.

http://www.nongnu.org/renameutils/

Answer (score 7):

Métamorphose

https://github.com/metamorphose

may be a little difficult to handle, but really powerful!

Comment: I really like this one. It is quite powerful and runs on all major platforms.

Answer (score 5):

If you like the shell and perl regular expressions I'd recommend `rename`. It's as plain as it's name.

Answer (score 4):

thunar file manager is a GUI with a bulk rename option

http://thunar.xfce.org/pwiki/documentation/bulk_renamer

it's not standard on Gnome but can be installed through the software centre

Answer (score 3):

If you are familiar with Emacs, I think nothing beats Dired for this task. Even if you don't use Emacs that often you may find Dired a handy tool.

`sudo aptitude install emacs23-nox`

Start Emacs Dired mode for a directory:

`emacs -nw path/to/dir/`

Now enter edit directory mode:

`C-x C-q` (that is Ctrl+x followed by Ctrl+q)

You can now edit the filenames like editing text in every plain text editor. You may even chose to replace the filenames using [regular expressions](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Regexp-Replace.html) (note that unfortunately Emacs uses a different syntax than PCRE).

For example, to rename files with counter (starting by 1):
`M-x replace-regexp` (that is Alt+x followed by the string "replace-regexp" typed in the minibuffer at the bottom of the screen).
Replace regexp:  `DSCN\([0-9]+\).JPG`
Replace with:    `\,(format "P%04d.jpg" (1 + \#))`

To reuse a counter in the filename:
`M-x replace-regexp`
Replace regexp: `DSCN\([0-9]+\).JPG`
Replace with: `\,(format "P%04d.jpg" (string-to-number \1))`

When finished, type:

`C-c C-c` (that is Ctrl+c followed by Ctrl+c)

Or alternatively press the following sequence to abort your changes:

`C-c Esc` (that is Ctrl+c followed by Esc)

Answer (score 2):

I tend to use [mmv](http://packages.ubuntu.com/maverick/mmv), which is command-line based, and has a somewhat quirky expression syntax but tend to solve most of my problems.

Answer (score 1):

If you use Nautilus and know how Nautilus Scripts work, you could use [nautilus-renamer](https://github.com/trhura/nautilus-renamer).

Answer (score 1):

**`find -execdir rename`**

This renames files and directories with a regular expression affecting only basenames, for example:

```
PATH=/usr/bin find . -depth -execdir rename "s/^find/replace/" '{}' \;
```

or to affect files only:

```
PATH=/usr/bin find . -type f -execdir rename "s/^find/replace/" '{}' \;
```

I have explained it in more detail at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16541582/find-multiple-files-and-rename-them-in-linux/54163971#54163971

Answer (score 0):

On the command line theres also the possibility to use magic of sed and shell:

```
ls *.c | sed "s#\(.*\)\.c#mv \0 \1.cpp#" | sh
```

Comment: That doesn't seem to work as printed. You might also use '#' or other character instead of "\" as separators in examples for possibly more clarity. e.g., ` ls *.c | sed 's#([a-z]*)\.c#\1.cpp#' `  (This example is not do the rename, just to display the new filename, for simplicity)

Comment: +1 I find it a really nice way (that additionally works across all distros), without installing anything. But I would probably use the `-d` switch for `ls` to avoid listing content of directories which might also end with `.c` (most of the times not an issue, but still ..).

Answer (score 0):

For me the pyRenamer worked the best. Nothing (sadly) comes close to Total Commanders built it renaming tool. pyRenamer doesn't integrate with Krusader but considering the fact, that you don't use the renaming tools that often anyway, pyRenamer is a very good option.

Answer (score 0):

This is the tool I use: [rnm](https://github.com/neurobin/rnm) ([man page](https://docs.neurobin.org/man/man1/rnm.html)) ([more examples](https://neurobin.org/docs/unix/rnm))

Some Usage:

```
rnm file-name -ns new-filename             # single file
rnm ./* -ns '/n//i/'                       # files will be sorted and indexed.
rnm ./* -rs '/search/new/g'                # 'search' in filenames will be replaced with 'new'
rnm ./* -ns '/fn//i/' -ss 'search'         # only files/directories which contain 'search' in their name will be indexed (renamed).
rnm ./* -ns '/fn//id/' -fo                 # file only mode, directories will be ignored.
rnm ./* -ns '/fn//id/' -fo -dp -1          # recursive to subdirectories all the way.

etc...
```

Comment: The webpage link goes to https://neurobin.org/projects/softwares/unix/rnm/ and gives a 404.

Comment: @muru : hmm, something happened to the page, updated it to man page link.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I use [Ant Renamer](http://www.antp.be/software/renamer) with Wine because nothing I've tried (Métamorphose, PyRenamer, GPRename, KRename) is as powerful, easy to install and easy to use. And it's still FOSS so I don't see the problem.

Answer (score 0):

`Krename` is a KDE GUI for renaming files, generally found in most package managers.

This answer applies to removing leading numbers that may be found in music files such as mp3s. But `Krename` does mass rename as well.

1. Load selected files or folder. Krename loads all files in the selected folder, just click on <kbd>Open</kbd> without having to individually select all files.
2. Go to the `Destination` tab to overwrite or copy files to another folder.

   [image]
3. Go to the `Filename` tab, then to the `Advanced Filename` tab.

   [image: "Advanced Filename" image showing the default settings.]
4. Start by removing the token `$` in the `Template` window. A change takes place in the `Renamed` window below. No filenames appear, only the file extensions.

   [image: 3. Image shows that the filenames have been removed, leaving the file extensions.]
5. Click on <kbd>Insert Part of Filename...</kbd> and select the parts of the filename you want to keep. This operation will include all the files and the changes will be obvious in the `Renamed` window below.

   [image: 4. "Insert Part of Filename..." image showing how to select the filename by highlighting the preferred sections.]
6. Click <kbd>OK</kbd>. The files are renamed without the leading numbers.

   [image: 5. Final results showing.]
7. Finally, click <kbd>Finished</kbd> at the bottom right corner.

Answer (score 0):

A newer GUI batch rename utility that runs on Linux (it also works on Mac and Windows) is [Inviska Rename](http://ttps://www.inviska.com/rename/).

[image]

Besides the usual rename functions like replacing a portion of the text with some other text, inserting or removing text, renaming file extensions, and so on, this tool can rename folders, rename music based on tags, and rename photos using their Exif information. It can even batch rename using file attributes like the creation or modification date.

Other features include previewing the new filenames and undoing the batch rename, which I find very useful.

[Source](https://www.linuxuprising.com/2019/05/gui-to-batch-rename-files-on-linux-with.html)

Comment: Unfortunately, site now offline and app unavailable: https://web.archive.org/web/20191009192550/https://www.inviska.com/rename/

Answer (score -1):

The cross-platform file manager **[Double Commander](https://doublecmd.sourceforge.io/)** (released under GNU GPL 2 license) includes a fairly powerful "Multi Rename Tool":

[image: doublcmd-multi-rename tool]

I used to use the very powerful [Bulk Rename Utility](https://www.bulkrenameutility.co.uk/) for Windows under WINE, but the Double Commander tool gets me most of the way there.