# How do I change extension of multiple files recursively from the command line?

Tags: command-line, bash, rename, batch-rename

I have many files with `.abc` extension and want to change them to `.edefg`
How to do this from command line ?

I have a root folder with many sub-folders, so the solution should work recursively.

Comment: See http://askubuntu.com/questions/10607/what-mass-file-renaming-tools-are-available

Comment: This whole thread would improve a lot if we could replace on question and answers: `.edefg` --> `.def`.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21985492/recursively-change-file-extensions-in-bash

Answer (score 122):

A portable way (which will work on any POSIX compliant system):

```bsh
find /the/path -depth -name "*.abc" -exec sh -c 'mv "$1" "${1%.abc}.edefg"' _ {} \;
```

In bash4, you can use globstar to get recursive globs (**):

```bsh
shopt -s globstar
for file in /the/path/**/*.abc; do
  mv "$file" "${file%.abc}.edefg"
done
```

The (perl) `rename` command in Ubuntu can rename files using perl regular expression syntax, which you can combine with globstar or `find`:

```bsh
# Using globstar
shopt -s globstar
files=(/the/path/**/*.abc)  

# Best to process the files in chunks to avoid exceeding the maximum argument 
# length. 100 at a time is probably good enough. 
# See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/095
for ((i = 0; i < ${#files[@]}; i += 100)); do
  rename 's/\.abc$/.edefg/' "${files[@]:i:100}"
done

# Using find:
find /the/path -depth -name "*.abc" -exec rename 's/\.abc$/.edefg/' {} +
```

Also see http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/030

Comment: the first one simply appends the new extension onto the old one, it doesn't replace...

Comment: @user2757729, it does replace it. `"${1%.abc}"` expands to the value of `$1` except without `.abc` at the end. See [faq 100](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/100) for more on shell string manipulations.

Comment: I ran this on a ~70k files file structure... at least on my shell it most definitely did not replace it.

Comment: Sorry just set up a test dir structure and it seems to be working.  Wonder what I did wrong yesterday.

Comment: aren't this kind of expansion bash specific? In that case, wouldn't it  be better to use `bash` instead of `sh` in the first command?

Comment: @pqnet, `${1%.abc}` is [defined by POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_02), if that's what you're referring to.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. The first line worked great on Ubuntu 14.04, and I was able to add an additional command in there to rename all the files in my _fossil_ repo at the same time (e.g. '<your command' && mv ...').

Comment: @user2757729 You probably left the "abc" in `${1%.abc}...`

Comment: In case anyone else is wondering what the underscore is doing in the first command, it's needed because with `sh -c` _the first argument is assigned to $0 and any remaining arguments are assigned to the positional parameters_. So the `_` is a dummy argument, and '{}' is the first positional argument to `sh -c`.

Comment: xargs version, `find -iname "*.img" -print0 | xargs -L 1 -I {} -0 sh -c 'mv "{}" "${{}%.img}.iso"'`

Comment: @RayFoss that's broken, and attempts to inject the filenames into the shell. Pass the filename as argument instead, then use "$1" to retrieve it inside the script. `...|xargs ... -0 sh -c 'mv "$1" "${1%.img}.iso"' sh {}`

Comment: Thank @geirha! That really worked for me I had to rename a lot of converted flac files to mp3, do you believe you could explain in detail what each parameter does? I know that $1 is the first commanline argument, but I'm super interested in knowing the % and _ arguments, and why {} is right there at the end. I've looked up online but didn't find any particular explanatio nfor your usage. And % and _ show a lot of info that I don't think is what you applied. I would super appreciate it!

Answer (score 59):

This will do the required task if all the files are in the same folder

```
rename 's/.abc$/.edefg/' *.abc
```

To rename the files  recursively use this:

```
find /path/to/root/folder -type f -name '*.abc' -print0 | xargs -0 rename 's/.abc$/.edefg/'
```

Comment: Or `rename 's/.abc$/.edefg/' /path/to/root/folder/**/*.abc` in a modern version of Bash.

Comment: Great thanks Adam for giving me a tip on how to use *.abc in folders recursively!

Comment: Great tip, thanks !  Where can I find more documentation about the little piece of regex's syntax ?  Like what's the `s` at the beginning, and what other options can I use in there.  Thanks !

Comment: @AdamByrtek I just failed with your suggestion on Utopic. ('no such files' or some such.)

Comment: @Anto very late but fwiw and for future reader the `s` at the beginning stands for `substitute` the `/` are the delimiters which can, in theory, be any character as long that character doesn't need to be replaced and the `$` mean "at the end of the string" which comes from regex

Answer (score 16):

One problem with recursive renames is that whatever method you use to locate the files, it passes the whole path to `rename`, not just the file name. That makes it hard to do complex renames in nested folders.

I use `find`'s `-execdir` action to solve this problem. If you use `-execdir` instead of `-exec`, the specified command is run from the subdirectory containing the matched file. So, instead of passing the whole path to `rename`, it only passes `./filename`. That makes it much easier to write the regex.

```
find /the/path -type f \
               -name '*.abc' \
               -execdir rename 's/\.\/(.+)\.abc$/version1_$1.abc/' '{}' \;
```

In detail:

- `-type f` means only look for files, not directories
- `-name '*.abc'` means only match filenames that end in .abc
- `'{}'` is the placeholder that marks the place where `-execdir` will insert the found path. The single-quotes are required, to allow it to handle file names with spaces and shell characters.
- The backslashes after `-type` and `-name` are the bash line-continuation character. I use them to make this example more readable, but they are not needed if you put your command all on one line.
- However, the backslash at the end of the `-execdir` line is required. It is there to escape the semicolon, which terminates the command run by `-execdir`. Fun!

Explanation of the regex:

- `s/` start of the regex
- `\.\/` match the leading ./ that -execdir passes in. Use \ to escape the . and / metacharacters (note: this part vary depending on your version of `find`. See comment from user @apollo)
- `(.+)` match the filename. The parentheses capture the match for later use
- `\.abc` escape the dot, match the abc
- `$` anchor the match at the end of the string
- `/` marks the end of the "match" part of the regex, and the start of the "replace" part
- `version1_` add this text to every file name
- `$1` references the existing filename, because we captured it with parentheses. If you use multiple sets of parentheses in the "match" part, you can refer to them here using $2, $3, etc.
- `.abc` the new file name will end in .abc. No need to escape the dot metacharacter here in the "replace" section
- `/` end of the regex

Before

```
tree --charset=ascii

|-- a_file.abc
|-- Another.abc
|-- Not_this.def
`-- dir1
    `-- nested_file.abc
```

After

```
tree --charset=ascii

|-- version1_a_file.abc
|-- version1_Another.abc
|-- Not_this.def
`-- dir1
    `-- version1_nested_file.abc
```

---

Hint: `rename`'s -n option is useful. It does a dry run and shows you what names it will change, but does not make any changes.

Comment: Thanks for the details explanation, but strangely, when I try this, the `--execdir` did not pass in the leading `./` so the `\.\/` part in the regex can be omitted. May that is because I am on OSX not ubuntu

Answer (score 5):

Another portable way:

```
find /the/path -depth -type f -name "*.abc" -exec sh -c 'mv -- "$1" "$(dirname "$1")/$(basename "$1" .abc).edefg"' _ '{}' \;
```

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! While this is a valuable answer, I recommend expanding it (by editing) to explain *how and why* that command works.

Answer (score 5):

```
# Rename all *.txt to *.text
for f in *.txt; do 
mv -- "$f" "${f%.txt}.text"
done
```

Also see the entry on why you shouldn't parse `ls`.

Edit: if you have to use basename your syntax would be:

```
for f in *.txt; do
mv -- "$f" "$(basename "$f" .txt).text"
done
```

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/19654/changing-extension-to-multiple-files

Answer (score 2):

I'd use the [mmv command](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/mmv.1.html)
from the [package of the same name](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/mmv):

```
mmv ';*.abc' '#1#2.edefg'
```

The `;` matches zero or more `*/` and corresponds to `#1` in the replacement. The `*` corresponds to `#2`. The non-recursive version would be

```
mmv '*.abc' '#1.edefg'
```

Answer (score 1):

**Rename files and directories with `find -execdir | rename`**

If you are going to rename both files and directories not simply with a suffix, then this is a good pattern:

```
PATH="$(echo "$PATH" | sed -E 's/(^|:)[^\/][^:]*//g')" \
  find . -depth -execdir rename 's/findme/replaceme/' '{}' \;
```

The awesome `-execdir` option does a `cd` into the directory before executing the `rename` command, unlike `-exec`.

`-depth` ensure that the renaming happens first on children, and then on parents, to prevent potential problems with missing parent directories.

`-execdir` is required because rename does not play well with non-basename input paths, e.g. the following fails:

```
rename 's/findme/replaceme/g' acc/acc
```

The `PATH` hacking is required because `-execdir` has one very annoying drawback: `find` is extremely opinionated and refuses to do anything with `-execdir` if you have any relative paths in your `PATH` environment variable, e.g. `./node_modules/.bin`, failing with:

> find: The relative path ‘./node_modules/.bin’ is included in the PATH environment variable, which is insecure in combination with the -execdir action of find.  Please remove that entry from $PATH

See also: [Why using the '-execdir' action is insecure for directory which is in the PATH?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/621132/why-using-the-execdir-action-is-insecure-for-directory-which-is-in-the-path/1109378#1109378)

`-execdir` is a GNU find [extension to POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/find.html). `rename` is Perl based and comes from the `rename` package. Tested in Ubuntu 18.10.

**Rename lookahead workaround**

If your input paths don't come from `find`, or if you've had enough of the relative path annoyance, we can use some Perl lookahead to safely rename directories as in:

```
git ls-files | sort -r | xargs rename 's/findme(?!.*\/)\/?$/replaceme/g' '{}'
```

I haven't found a convenient analogue for `-execdir` with `xargs`: https://superuser.com/questions/893890/xargs-change-working-directory-to-file-path-before-executing/915686

The `sort -r` is required to ensure that files come after their respective directories, since longer paths come after shorter ones with the same prefix.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did and worked pretty just the way I wanted. I used the `mv` command. I had multiple `.3gp` files and I wanted to rename them all to `.mp4`

Here's a short oneliner for it:

```
for i in *.3gp; do mv -- "$i" "ren-$i.mp4"; done
```

Which simply scans through the current directory, picks up all .3gp files, then renames (using the mv) into `ren-name_of_file.mp4`

Comment: That will rename `file.3gp` to `file.3gp.mp4`, which might not be what most people want.

Comment: @muru but the principle still exist. Simply select *any* extension then specify the destination extension to get them renamed. The `.3gp` or `.mp4` here were just for illustration purposes.

Comment: The syntax is preferrable, one-liner and easy to understand. However, I would use `basename "$i" .mp4` to remove the previous extension instead of "ren-$i.mp4".

Comment: True. Good point.

Answer (score 0):

I found an easy way to achieve this. To change extensions of many files from jpg to pdf, use:

```
for file in /path/to; do mv $file $(basename -s jpg $file)pdf ; done
```