# How to rename file extension to lowercase?

Tags: command-line, bash, rename, extension

I know [this question has been asked (and answered) before](https://askubuntu.com/q/35922/62483), but it seems my situation is unique, because I cannot have any of the solution to work.

Running, I need to rename all my photos from `*.JPG` to `*.jpg`.

Let's say I don't need recursive, just all the pictures in the same folder.

The problem I meet is this one:

```
mv: ‘P1010521.JPG’ and ‘p1010521.jpg’ are the same file
```

Same problem using rename, with that kind of command:

```
rename 's/\.JPG$/.jpg/' *.JPG
P1020558.JPG not renamed: P1020558.jpg already exists
```

Comment: Came on, you are at one step to make it! What script do you have by now?

Comment: Which filesystem the files are on? I guess it's not `ext4`...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It is really simple:

1. Rename to something else than the same value with different case

   ```
   rename 's/\.JPG$/\.jpgaux/' *.JPG
   ```
2. Now rename that something else to `.jpg` back again, but lowercase this time

   ```
   rename 's/\.jpgaux$/\.jpg/' *.jpgaux
   ```

#### Demo: http://paste.ubuntu.com/8853245/

Source: [How to change extension of multiple files from command line?](https://askubuntu.com/a/35930/62483) Thanks to [Chakra](https://askubuntu.com/users/2725/chakra)!

Comment: Smart ... or stupid of me, depends on the point of view.Tx

Comment: None of both.. Remember to mark it as accepted to close the question :)

Comment: @Lucio,...I guess that the files are on a case-insensitive filesystem (`vfat`, `ntfs`); otherwise the "plain" rename would work.

Comment: @Rmano absolutely.

Comment: @Lucio I think you misunderstood the OP's question. He/She wants to rename `P1020558.JPG` to `P1020558.jpg` but he/she has another file which is that exist with same name `P1020558.jpg`. Then gets the error: `P1020558.JPG not renamed: P1020558.jpg already exists`. Also your solution is wrong because the name of files are the same and the solution doesn't effect any changes and still he/she will have the error. for example test on `touch Image{1..5}.JPG;touch Image{1..5}.jpg` your own answer.

Comment: +1, but escape the `.`s so they won't match any character. (I'd just edit, but 2 char changes are not accepted and I didn't want to write four more chars of garbage)

Comment: @KasiyA before your edit, that was not the case. My answer solves the *original* OP issue.

Comment: @thatotherguy I don't understand your problem but feel free to edit the answer :-)

Comment: @Lucio If author use Fat32 file system then there is no different between `P1010521.JPG’ or ‘p1010521.jpg’`. So my edit doesn't cause any change on OP's Q. yes your solution is right if OP use fat32 file system but no where he/she said that +1 :)

Comment: No where he/she said that it was not the file system :)

Comment: How could we rename on a case-sensitive filesystem? `rename 'y/a-z/A-Z/' /tmp/*.jpg` -> `Can't rename /tmp/*.jpg /TMP/*.JPG: No such file or directory`

Answer (score 2):

If αғsнιη is right in his comment, and I think he is, OP's problem is that a similarly named file already exists. If that is the case, the script will have to check if the targeted file name (lowercase) already exists, and (only) if so, rename the original file additionally (not only lowercase extension) to prevent the name error, e.g.

```
image1.JPG
```

to

```
renamed_image1.jpg
```

since `image1.jpg` would raise an error

If so, a python solution to rename could be:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import os
import shutil
import sys

directory = sys.argv[1]
for file in [f for f in os.listdir(directory) if f.endswith(".JPG")]:
        newname = file[:file.rfind(".")]+".jpg"
        if os.path.exists(directory+"/"+newname):
                newname = "renamed_"+newname
        shutil.move(directory+"/"+file, directory+"/"+newname)
```

The script renames:

```
image1.JPG -> image1.jpg
```

but if `image1.jpg` already exists:

```
image1.JPG -> renamed_image1.jpg
```

###How to use

Copy the script into an empty file, save it as `rename.py`, make it executable and run it by the command:

```
<script> <directory_of_files>
```

Comment: Did you read that the question mentions the following error? `mv: ‘P1010521.JPG’ and ‘P1010521.jpg’ are the same file`. _Are the same file…_

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf that seems in contradiction with the fact that renaming is impossible in his command (.JPG and .jpg)

Comment: Where's the contradiction?

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf when I try his command with a bunch of JPGs, they are simply renamed, so the targeted name *must* already exist in his case.

Comment: Very likely, OP is on a case-insensitive filesystem (as was already mentioned in several comments). As an example, try it yourself on a pendrive with a FAT32 partition `;)`.

Comment: And to get the error `are the same file`, do: `touch gniourf; mv gniourf Gniourf`.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf No it's case-sensitive. according to `P1020558.JPG not renamed: P1020558.jpg already exists`. both files `P1020558.JPG` and `P1020558.jpg` already exist on his partition and also according to mv command that said both file are "‘P1010521.JPG’ and ‘P1010521.jpg’" are the same file. then they both are exist and that's not case-insensitive.

Comment: @KasiyA do you understand what _are the same file_ means?

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf Yes I know if the file is copy of the same file with *different name*. and also I understand `P1020558.JPG not renamed: P1020558.jpg already exists` what is the meaning of this command. If you are not sure. [test it for yourself](http://askubuntu.com/questions/546426/how-to-rename-file-extension-to-lowercase/547350#comment749920_546429) all of these files are the same file with different names. And the OP nowhere said he/she use FAT32 file system.

Comment: @KasiyA you know what? try it first on your own on a pendrive with a FAT32 partition. Then you'll see…

Answer (score 2):

really easy with mmv:

```
sudo apt install mmv

mmv \*.JPEG \#1.jpeg
```

Answer (score 1):

This works best I think, as perl supports running code in the regex

`rename -n 's/(\.[A-Z]+$)/lc($1)/ge' *.*[A-Z]*`

remove the `-n` to actually rename the files