# Changing files' extention in loop

Tags: command-line, bash, mv

I want to change extentions of a few files, using loop.

```
#!/bin/bash
read -p "type the path for folder " folder                                 
read -p "type the extention of files to be renamed " ext
read -p "type the extention you want to add " next
next=.$next
ext=.$ext
if [ $? -eq 0 ]
then
e=`ls $folder/*$ext | cut -d '.' -f1`                                      
for i in `ls $folder/*$ext`
do
mv $i $e
mv $e $e$next
done
ls $folder/*.$next
fi
```

I'm failing.

Comment: [Why you shouldn't parse the output of `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [10.1. Manipulating Strings](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/string-manipulation.html)-[TLDP.org](http://tldp.org/) for a thorough discussion of bash string manipulation. This [unix se answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/19656/253061) has the essential part of the answer. Just change "txt" to `$ext` and "text" to `$next`. The resulting script could look like.

```bash
#!/bin/bash
read -p "type the path for folder " folder                                 
read -p "type the extension of files to be renamed " ext
read -p "type the extension you want to add " next
# TODO add sanity checks for the user supplied input
cd $folder
# rename
#rename "s/.$ext$/.$next/" *.$ext
# mv in a loop
for f in *.$ext; do 
# the '--' marks the end of command options so that files starting with '-' wont cause problems.
# Replaces the first match for '.$ext' with '.$next'.
#mv -- "$f" "${f/$ext/$next}"
# Replaces the any match for '.$ext' with '.$next'.
#mv -- "$f" "${f//$ext/$next}"
# Replaces front-end match of for '$ext' with '$next'
#mv -- "$f" "${f/#$ext/$next}"
# Replaces back-end match of for '$ext' with '$next'
mv -- "$f" "${f/%$ext/$next}"
done
```

This [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/35922/how-to-change-extension-of-multiple-files-from-command-line) has many approaches that don't necessarily need a loop. I would favor `rename`, see the commented lines in the above script.

Comment: J. Starnes, Could you explain more this: mv -- "$f" "${f//.$ext/.$next}"