# Change duplicated extension of multiple files recursively from the command line

Tags: command-line, rename, zsh, batch-rename

My question is almost the same as [those](https://askubuntu.com/questions/35922/how-do-i-change-extension-of-multiple-files-recursively-from-the-command-line), however, its solution doesn't work my for my case.
I'd like to remove duplicated extension (in my case `.zip.zip`) and have only one (i.e. `.zip`).
I tried:

```
rename 's/.zip/.zip$/.zip/' *.zip.zip
```

and

```
find . -depth -name "*.zip.zip" -exec rename 's/\.zip\.zip$/.zip/' {} +
```

But in both case no file was renamed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recursively renaming files using globstar and rename:

```
$ shopt -s globstar; rename 's/\.zip$//' **/*.zip.zip
```

Renaming files using mmv:

```
$ mmv ';*.zip.zip' '#1#2.zip'
       12            ^ ^
```

- `;` matches files at any depth in the directory tree.
- `*` Matches any char zero or more times.
- `#` References to the nth wildcard char in the from pattern.

Comment: Very nice explanation. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The following did the trick.

`find . -depth -name "*.zip.zip" -exec sh -c 'mv "$1" "${1%.zip.zip}.zip"' _ {} \;`