# How do I easily rename multiple files using command line?

Tags: command-line, rename

One of the ways I quickly rename files in Windows is

```
F2 > Rename > Tab (to next file) > Rename ...
```

But in Ubuntu/Nautilus, I can't tab to next file. But being on Linux, I think there must be a command line alternative.

However, sometimes, I may want more control over how to rename specific files. In that case, perhaps its better to be able to tab to the next file

Comment: Could you define "more control"? Not sure what you're asking exactly..

Comment: I think this question is not answered. What you are asking for (F2 and then jump in F2 mode to the next file) is currently not available I think in Nautilus.

Answer (score 210, accepted):

I use `rename` all the time.  It is pretty simple, but hopefully you know basic regex:

```
rename "s/SEARCH/REPLACE/g"  *
```

This will replace the string `SEARCH` with `REPLACE` in every file (that is, `*`).  The `/g` means global, so if you had a `SEARCH_SEARCH.jpg`, it would be renamed `REPLACE_REPLACE.jpg`. If you didn't have `/g`, it would have only done substitution once, and thus now named `REPLACE_SEARCH.jpg`.  If you want case-insensitive, add `/i` (that would be, `/gi` or `/ig` at the end).

With regular expressions, you can do lots more.

Note that this `rename` is the [`prename`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/prename.1) (aka Perl `rename`) command, which supports complete Perl regular expressions. There is another `rename` which uses patterns, and is not as powerful. `prename` used to be installed by default on Ubuntu (along with Perl), but now you may have to do:

```
sudo apt install rename
```

---

Here are a few examples:

#### Prefix

**Add**:

```
rename 's/^/MyPrefix_/' *
```

- `document.pdf` renamed to `MyPrefix_document.pdf`

**Remove**:

Also you can remove unwanted strings.  Let's say you had 20 MP3 files named like `CD RIP 01 Song.mp3` and you wanted to remove the "CD RIP" part, and you wanted to remove that from all of them with one command.

```
rename 's/^CD RIP //' *
```

- `CD RIP 01 Song.mp3` to `01 Song.mp3`

Notice the extra space in `'^CD RIP '`, without the space all files would have a space as the first character of the file.  Also note, this will work without the `^` character, but would match `CD RIP`  in any part of the filename.  The `^` guarantees it only removes the characters if they are the beginning of the file.

#### Suffix

**Add**:

```
rename 's/$/_MySuffix/' *
```

- `document.pdf` renamed to `document.pdf_MySuffix`

**Change**:

```
rename 's/\.pdf$/.doc/' *
```

will change `Something.pdf` into `Something.doc`. (The reason for the backslash is, `.` is a wildcard character in regexp so `.pdf` matches `qPDF` whereas `\.pdf` only matches the exact string `.pdf`. Also very important to note, if you are not familiar with BASH, you must put backslashes in SINGLE quotes!  You may not omit quotes or use double quotes, or bash will try to translate them.  To bash `\.` *and* `"\."` equals `.`. (But double-quotes and backslashes are used, for example "\n" for a newline, but since `"\."` isn't a valid back escape sequence, it translates into `.`)

Actually, you can even enclose the parts of the string in quotes instead of the whole: `'s/Search/Replace/g'` is the same as `s/'Search'/'Replace'/g` and `s/Search/Replace/g` to BASH. You just have to be careful about special characters (and spaces).

---

I suggest using the `-n` option when you are not positive you have the correct regular expressions. It shows what would be renamed, then exits without doing it. For example:

```
rename -n s/'One'/'Two'/g *
```

This will list all changes it would have made, had you not put the `-n` flag there.  If it looks good, press <kbd>Up</kbd> to go back, then erase the `-n` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> (or replace it with `-v` to output all changes it makes).

**Note**: Ubuntu versions above 17.04 don't ship with `rename` by default, however it's still available in the repositories. Use `sudo apt install rename` to install it

Comment: How will I have a "dynamic" suffix. Like 001 - 010 etc. Possible?

Comment: Hmm.. I tried to write something up but it didn't work.  Mostly because, when I add 1 to 001, it adds to 2, not 002.  Otherwise, I could just use varaibles to hold the number position, then append it.  Also, I just remembered, before I knew about the `rename` commmand, this is what I did to append: `for f in *; do mv -v "$f" "prependThis$f"; done`

Comment: @jiewmeng Yes. Use `(?:\.[0-9]{3})$` in your pattern, it will match all 3 digit file extensions in a passive group. Example: `rename s/^my_favorite_movie.avi(?:\.[0-9]{3})$/random_movie.avi/ *`. Have a look at this [regex cheat sheet](http://www.addedbytes.com/cheat-sheets/regular-expressions-cheat-sheet/).

Comment: @sergio91pt it is a nice regex cheat sheet. But what it is about? Must be perl - but a can't find such a note there.

Comment: @Adobe Its a general one for "perl based regex". Look at the note about the + sign and the column about POSIX Character Classes.

Comment: @[Sergiy](https://askubuntu.com/users/295286/sergiy-kolodyazhnyy) Perhaps one more very useful case to be added into your answer: **Insert after** `rename -n 's/Matched_string/$&Inserted_string/' *` *For example, if we need to insert a _STRING after the YYYY-MM-DD date pattern in the beginning of files or directories:* `rename -n 's/^[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}/$&_STRING/' *`

Comment: If you're using the less powerful `rename` command that uses patterns, the syntax is `rename "SEARCH" "REPLACE" *`

Answer (score 22):

Try [pyrenamer](http://packages.ubuntu.com/pyrenamer).

It's not integrated with nautilus, but it gets the job done. [Here](http://2buntu.com/891/pyrenamer-go-ubuntu/) is a review.

[Thunar](http://packages.ubuntu.com/thunar) (part of XFCE) also has a renamer that you can run separately.

[image: Thunar bulk renamer]

Comment: thanks for mentioning Thunar functionality. If you have Thunar - select files in folder and press F2.

Answer (score 10):

There seems to be a project on launchpad called [nautilus-renamer](https://launchpad.net/nautilus-renamer). You can install it by running `make install` once you download the script and untar it. It seems to have some functionalities or if you do know some programming may be you could just enhance it to your need as it is just a python script.

[image]

Answer (score 8):

Not really the same question as [How can rename many files at once?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/10607/what-mass-file-renaming-tools-are-available/23055#23055) but I'm going to suggest the same program that I suggested in that answer: **qmv**.

qmv is a handy tool from the renameutils package. It enables you to use your favorite text editor to rename files. Combined with the power of vim, you have an excellent renaming utility.

I usually invoke it like `qmv -f do` in the dir where I want to rename a bunch of files. Or if I want to rename recursively `qmv -R -f do`.

Whenever I have the need to rename multiple files, I always fall back on qmv (and vim).

http://www.nongnu.org/renameutils/

Comment: I just tried this based on your suggestion. This is really the most awesome tool if you use vim!

Comment: I'm trying to figure out if one can remove files in a similar way. If not, there's vifm

Answer (score 7):

In the command line, to rename a single file the command is simply

```
mv file1.txt file2.txt
```

If you want to do it in batch, you'll probably want to do it via a script. If you provide more details I or someone else can probably whip one up for you. That said, a script to append stuff to a file might look like this:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
for file in *
do
    # separate the file name from its extension
    if [[ $file == *.* ]]; then
      ext="${file##*.}"
      fname="${file%.*}"
      mv "$file" "${fname}_APPENDSTUFFHERE.$ext"
    else
      mv "$file" "${file}_APPENDSTUFFHERE"
    fi
done
```

Depending on exactly how you need things renamed this will likely be tweaked, for instance if you have specific renaming rules to follow. (Personally I'd do this via a Perl script since my bash-foo is not that great, but that's just me.)

Note that I got the separation of filename and extension from [a previously asked question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/965053/extract-filename-and-extension-in-bash).

Answer (score 7):

In case you want to do it without command line, similarly to what you have been doing in Windows, use **right arrow key** instead of **tab key**. This will select the next file just as tab does in Windows.

Comment: It is not the same: you would still need ENTER to finish renaming, arrow key to move to the next file, and F2 to rename it. TAB does it in 1 step once you are renaming a file.

Comment: @MestreLion But it's very similar to algorithm described in the question and does not require neither any additional software nor command-line operations. Sort of being user-friendly.

Comment: True, you were the only answer that at least *tried* the same approach as the original question. And the sad truth is that Nautilus has no such functionality. You can F2 to rename, but thats it. No TAB to automatically jump you to next file in rename mode already.

Answer (score 3):

If the only suitable option is renaming the files manually, a great way to do that is using [`vidir`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/vidir.1.html) (in the [`moreutils`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/moreutils) package):

```bsh
sudo add-apt-repository universe && sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install moreutils
```

```
DESCRIPTION
       vidir allows editing of the contents of a directory in a text editor.
       If no directory is specified, the current directory is edited.

       When editing a directory, each item in the directory will appear on
       its own numbered line. These numbers are how vidir keeps track of what
       items are changed. Delete lines to remove files from the directory, or
       edit filenames to rename files. You can also switch pairs of numbers
       to swap filenames.

       Note that if "-" is specified as the directory to edit, it reads a
       list of filenames from stdin and displays those for editing.
       Alternatively, a list of files can be specified on the command line.
```

## Examples

---

### Renaming files selectively

Current working directory's content:

```
.
├── bar
├── baz
└── foo
```

Run `vidir`, rename the filenames in the lines containing the filenames you wish to rename; hit <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> and <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>:

[image: screenshot3]

```
.
├── bar.bak
├── baz.old
└── foo.new
```

---

### Switching filenames selectively

Current working directory's content:

```
.
├── bar
├── baz
└── foo
```

Current working directory's files' content:

```bsh
$ for f in *; do printf '- %s:\n\n' "$f"; cat "$f"; echo; done
- bar:

This is bar

- baz:

This is baz

- foo:

This is foo

$
```

Run `vidir`, switch the numbers in the lines containing the filenames you wish to switch; hit <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> and <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>:

[image: screenshot4]

```
.
├── bar
├── baz
└── foo
```

```bsh
$ for f in *; do printf '- %s:\n\n' "$f"; cat "$f"; echo; done
- bar:

This is foo

- baz:

This is bar

- foo:

This is baz

$
```

---

### Removing files selectively

Current working directory's content:

```
.
├── bar
├── baz
└── foo
```

Run `vidir`, remove the lines containing the files you wish to delete; hit <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> and <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>:

[image: screenshot2]

```
.
└── baz
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm using krename. It is a GUI app. It could read mp3 tags and so on.

It exists as a separate app as well as a part of Krusader.

There's also a `rename` script - which is a part of standard perl installation (You probably have it installed). Check it out with `man rename`.