# How to delete part of a name of 195 diffrent files in one folder?

Tags: rename

I have 195 files in one other folder. Every single one has a combination of numbers and letters in [] brackets in front of its description. Example: `[12hjk534m45] description`.

Is it possible to delete the brackets and its contents with a command?

I hoped to do it with `rename` command and the syntax `[abc]`? 
How would that command look like?

Answer (score 1):

```bsh
rename -n 's:^\[.*\](.*):$1:' *

[02Rarev]QgysLJF renamed as QgysLJF
[0rwCtGh]cGdxnWH renamed as cGdxnWH
[1B2CMhq]M91oPHh renamed as M91oPHh
[1BMD7N3]0nYVP0b renamed as 0nYVP0b
[1MjkCZu]WBPYXKG renamed as WBPYXKG
[2HoSmD7]aLWLmpf renamed as aLWLmpf
```

`^\[.*\]` matches from beginning`^` of files for brackets and everything inside pair of it which is followed by anything`(.*)`. So with `(.*)` we just captured a group of anything after brackets that contains only files description then in replacement section `s/.../REPLACEMENT/` of rename command I replaced all files names with description part by using [back-reference](http://www.regular-expressions.info/backref.html) of captured group(`$1` refer to index of first captured group`(.*)`).

You can also use rename with class of characters matching:

```bsh
rename -n 's:^\[([0-9A-Za-z]*)\](.*):$1:' *
```

---

<sub>[How to create multiple files with different names and different extensions?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/169276/72456)</sub>

Comment: I think something like `rename 's/\[[^]]\]//' *` would be slightly faster (but not to any extent noticeable with just 200 files). Also, it shpuld probably be noted that the `-n` flag tells rename to just report what it will do; to actually rename the files, you need to get rid of the `-n`.

Comment: @evilsoup I tested it with two different commands on 100,000 files. one with deleting part of match and second with renaming but I get a little slow than from fist one. [test result](http://paste.ubuntu.com/9491205/)

Answer (score 0):

There's a really brilliant program for doing things like this called GPRename, it's in the software centre.

(Here's info on the commands:

http://tips.webdesign10.com/how-to-bulk-rename-files-in-linux-in-the-terminal

Looks to like what you want is there but you'll have to figure it out.. or just use GPRename!

great explanation of it here too: [How to easily rename files using command line?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/58546/how-to-easily-rename-files-using-command-line?rq=1))