# Renaming a word in the filename of all *.jpg files

Tags: 12.04

I am trying to rename a word in the file name of multiple JPEG files
from **Hoddesden to Hoddesdan**.

How can I do it on the Ubuntu command line?

#### Examples

```
R59-GBR_Hoddesden_2015-08-21_15-48-00-190_UNKNOWN.jpg
to 
YR59-GBR_Hoddesdan_2015-08-21_15-48-00-190_UNKNOWN.jpg 

YR59FRP-GBR_Hoddesden_2015-08-21_15-47-59-222_APPROACH
to
YR59FRP-GBR_Hoddesdan_2015-08-21_15-47-59-222_APPROACH
```

Comment: Do you mean `YR59FRP-GBR_Hoddesden_2015-08-21_15-47-59-222_APPROACH.jpg` instead of `YR59FRP-GBR_Hoddesden_2015-08-21_15-47-59-222_APPROACH`?

Comment: Also: http://askubuntu.com/questions/58546/how-to-easily-rename-files-using-command-line and quite a few others :)

Comment: @JacobVlijm I would say, a ton =)

Answer (score 11):

With `rename`

```bash
rename 's/Hoddesden/Hoddesdan/' *.jpg
```

---

*Example*

```bash
% ls -laog *.jpg
-rw-rw-r-- 1 0 Sep  1 13:30 R59-GBR_Hoddesden_2015-08-21_15-48-00-190_UNKNOWN.jpg
-rw-rw-r-- 1 0 Sep  1 13:30 YR59FRP-GBR_Hoddesden_2015-08-21_15-47-59-222_APPROACH.jpg

% rename 's/Hoddesden/Hoddesdan/' *.jpg

% ls -laog *.jpg
-rw-rw-r-- 1 0 Sep  1 13:30 R59-GBR_Hoddesdan_2015-08-21_15-48-00-190_UNKNOWN.jpg
-rw-rw-r-- 1 0 Sep  1 13:30 YR59FRP-GBR_Hoddesdan_2015-08-21_15-47-59-222_APPROACH.jpg
```

Comment: Nice to hear that, but don't thank me, simply accept my answer with a click on the icon at the left hand side of my answer =)

Answer (score 6):

You can use `rename` (`prename`) :

```
rename -n 's/Hoddesden/Hoddesdan/' *Hoddesden*
```

`-n` is for dry run, if you are satisfied with the changes remove `-n` to let the operation take place :

```
rename 's/Hoddesden/Hoddesdan/' *Hoddesden*
```

Comment: What should I say? Simply: **;)**

Answer (score 5):

We also have `rename.ul` (`rename` is a perl command).

```
rename.ul Hoddesden Hoddesdan *Hoddesden*
```

---

```
$ ls 
R59-GBR_Hoddesden_2015-08-21_15-48-00-190_UNKNOWN.jpg
YR59FRP-GBR_Hoddesden_2015-08-21_15-47-59-222_APPROACH
$ rename.ul Hoddesden Hoddesdan *Hoddesden*
$ ls 
59-GBR_Hoddesdan_2015-08-21_15-48-00-190_UNKNOWN.jpg
YR59FRP-GBR_Hoddesdan_2015-08-21_15-47-59-222_APPROACH
```

Answer (score 1):

With [mmv](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hardy/man1/mmv.1.html), install by

```
sudo apt-get install mmv
```

and use as following:

```
mmv '*Hoddesden*.jpg' '#1Hoddesdan#2.jpg'
```

Comment: You need to install mmv 1st.