# Rename great number of files in ubuntu terminal

Tags: rename

I have some files which was written as : `test_026542_time0663550.5.jpeg` and I would like to rename as `test_0663550.jpeg` in order to classify easily by order number because I have some errors with the current names.

Comment: Flat directory or recursively? Any risk on dupes after renaming?

Comment: And are they all in the form: `test_X_timeY.Z.jpeg`?

Comment: What parts of the filename always change ? Which parts never change ?

Comment: Answer posted, please review

Answer (score 0):

Use the `rename` function. It's basic(prototype form) is `$ rename s/"SEARCH"/"REPLACE"/g  *`. This replaces the file "SEARCH" with "REPLACE". The `/g` means global, so if you had a "SEARCH SEARCH.jpg", it would be renamed "REPLACE REPLACE.jpg". The `*` is the extension type like `.mp3` or `.pdf`. So, your example would be:

`$ rename s/'test_026542_time0663550.5.jpeg'/'test_0663550_.jpeg'/g *`

[This](https://askubuntu.com/questions/58546/how-to-easily-rename-files-using-command-line) should help.

Comment: Thanks for your help ;) but i m trying to automate it because i have a thousand of files...

Comment: @user3601754 you can create a BASH script then.

Comment: i have some difficulties to see how to do that

Answer (score 0):

My battery is running out , so I'll make this short

**Find+awk oneliner**

```
 find . -type f -printf "%f\n" |  awk -F "_" 
    '{ORIG=$0;gsub(/\_[[:digit:]].*\_time/,"_");gsub(/\.[[:digit:]].*\.jpeg/,".jpeg"); NEW=$0;cmd="mv "ORIG" 
    "NEW;system(cmd)}'
```

**Demo**

```
testdir2:$ ls
test_13442_time1446925878.1.jpeg  test_27796_time1446925887.4.jpeg
test_25495_time1446925884.3.jpeg  test_29681_time1446925881.2.jpeg


testdir2:find . -type f -printf "%f\n" |  awk -F "_" 
'{ORIG=$0;gsub(/\_[[:digit:]].*\_time/,"_");gsub(/\.[[:digit:]].*\.jpeg/,".jpeg"); NEW=$0;cmd="mv "ORIG" 
"NEW;system(cmd)}' 

testdir2:$ ls
test_1446925878.jpeg  test_1446925881.jpeg  test_1446925884.jpeg  test_1446925887.jpeg
```