# Remove today's date string from all filenames in folder

Tags: bash, files, rename

I have a folder full of jpegs formatted like this:

```
0001_20210516_XYZ.jpg
0002_20210516_XYZ.jpg
123_20210516_XYZ.jpg
01_20210516_XYZ.jpg
```

and I want to rename all files so the date string in the middle is removed so the files look like:

```
0001_XYZ.jpg
0002_XYZ.jpg
123_XYZ.jpg
01_XYZ.jpg
```

I tried using [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/891539/remove-date-and-time-from-filenames) to write the regex to remove 8 digits using this code:

```
rename - 's/^_\d{8}\_//' *
```

But this did not do anything. I am not sure how to format this correctly so the middle date string is removed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To remove the first underscore and following 8 digits using the Perl-based `rename` (aka `file-rename`), you need to drop the start-of-line anchor `^`, and the second underscore (else you'll end up with `0001XYZ.jpg` etc.)

So:

```
rename -n 's/_\d{8}//' *_*_*.jpg
```

Alternatively you could use `mmv` (from the Ubuntu package of the same name):

```
mmv -n '*_*_*.jpg' '#1_#3.jpg'
```

In either case, the `-n` is for testing - remove it when you are happy with the proposed changes.

If you're stuck with the version of rename from `util-linux` (which is installed as `rename.ul` on my system) then likely the best you will be able to do is match the literal string `_20210516`:

```
rename.ul -vn _20210516 '' *_*_*.jpg
```

If you really need to remove *today's* date you could generalize that to

```
rename.ul -vn "_$(date +%Y%m%d)" '' *_*_*.jpg
```

(Note that `rename.ul from util-linux 2.34` **does** support a `-n` option, which I'm using here for demonstration purposes - adjust accordingly if your version doesn't).

Comment: This gives me the error `rename: invalid option -- 'n'

Usage:
 rename [options] expression replacement file...

Options:
 -v, --verbose    explain what is being done
 -s, --symlink    act on symlink target

 -h, --help     display this help and exit
 -V, --version  output version information and exit

For more details see rename(1).
` and when I run it without -n my filenames don't change :(

Comment: @Pad in that case the implementation of `rename` that you are using is not one that I am familiar with - my answer applies to the Perl-based one sometimes known as `file-rename`.

Comment: No problem, when I do -V I get `rename from util-linux 2.23.2` thank you for your help! I will keep trying.

Comment: @Pad I have added a couple of other options that may suit you better

Comment: Also known as [`prename`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/en/man1/prename.1p.html)

Comment: @steeldriver thank you - this worked perfectly `rename -v "_$(date +%Y%m%d)" '' *_*_*.jpg
`