# How to remove square brackets, any text inside, and space after & before the brackets?

Tags: command-line, bash, sed, batch-rename

I have a lot of photos that need to be renamed.

```
[Wedding] Happy Day_001 [February].jpg
[Mountain] Summer Camp_165 [May].jpg
[Beach] Music Fest_58 [August].jpg
```

I need all the square brackets to be removed. To do so, I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17522855/how-to-remove-square-brackets-and-any-text-inside) & [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/14838/sed-one-liner-to-delete-everything-between-a-pair-of-brackets).

Using `sed` command as in those pages, the space before and after the brackets is still there. In my case, I want the text inside, space before & after, and the brackets itself to be removed.

```
Happy Day_001.jpg  
Summer Camp_165.jpg  
Music Fest_58.jpg
```

To remove `[first]`　 & 　`[last]` brackets, how can I do that with a `sed` command?

Comment: Do you have the metadata (Wedding, Mountain, Beach, ...) as keywords in jpg files? It might be a good idea to update the EXIF first and only then rename the file.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to easily rename files using command line?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/58546/how-to-easily-rename-files-using-command-line)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`sed` is the wrong tool. It doesn't rename files. While you can pair it with something that can, it's simpler to use [`rename` from Perl](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/prename.1.html):

```
rename -n 's/\[.*?\]//g' *
```

With `-n`, `rename` will show what changes will be made. Run without `-n` to actually rename the files. `rename` is Perl, and in Perl, `.*?` is not a greedy match like `.*`, so you don't need to use tricks like `[^]]*`.

To remove surrounding whitespace as well:

```
rename -n 's/\s*\[.*?\]\s*//g' *
```

Comment: Ah, you're right. That's why I got an error. It's trying to edit the file itself rather than changing its name. I never used `sed` or `rename` before since `mv` is enough for me.Your answer is what i was looking for. It works perfectly! Thank you very much.

Answer (score 9):

You shouldn't use `sed` to rename files, but you can use the Perl program `rename`, for example:

```
$ rename -n 's/\[[^]]+\] ([^[]+) \[[^]]+\]/$1/' *
rename([Beach] Music Fest_58 [August].jpg, Music Fest_58.jpg)
rename([Mountain] Summer Camp_165 [May].jpg, Summer Camp_165.jpg)
rename([Wedding] Happy Day_001 [February].jpg, Happy Day_001.jpg)
```

Remove `-n` after testing to actually rename the files.

#### Notes

- `s/old/new` replace `old` with `new`
- `\[` literal `[`
- `[^[]+` some characters that are not `[`
- `(stuff)` save `stuff` for later to reference as `$1`, `$2` etc

This only works if your filenames are consistent. [muru's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/967963/527764) is much more portable.

Comment: It works! Thank you. It has many brackets that I don't understand. Maybe can you give me a reference about it to read?

Comment: Some of the brackets are literal and some are used for character classes (here just for negation with `^`). I explained a little in my notes. [Here's a small summary](http://jkorpela.fi/perl/regexp.html) of Perl regex which links to a bigger one. But the regex I use here is the same for `sed` and `grep` so the regex sections in `info sed`, for example, may help @SandiHidayat

Comment: Good ol' rename, love it