# How do I move numbers in filenames, in a batch renaming operation?

Tags: command-line, batch-rename

I have been trying to figure out how to rename files for the past few hours.

I have 2000 files that are like this:

```
file.1.pdb
file.2.pdb
file.3.pdb
```

I would like to rename these files to something like:

```
file.pdb.1
file.pdb.2
file.pdb.3
```

Comment: Didn't you mean *bash*?

Comment: Okay, my bad sorry guys, I did googled batch before commenting and didn't see the connection with the massive renaming of your files. Now that you say I get it :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to easily rename files using command line?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/58546/how-to-easily-rename-files-using-command-line)

Comment: I know it's on unix, and so this is super easy with the command line, but if you want a gui, then [Bulk Rename Utility](http://www.bulkrenameutility.co.uk/Main_Intro.php) is excellent.

Comment: Hey close voters - do you all really think we only need one question in the [batch-rename] tag? Is there anything in the linked post that actually helps with the task in this question, except the idea of using `rename`? It seems to me that if a batch renaming question has specific details, we should just *provide specific answers* to it.

Answer (score 16):

If you have `rename` installed, you can use

```
rename -n 's/(\.\d+)\.pdb$/.pdb$1/' *.pdb   # just watch what WOULD happen
rename    's/(\.\d+)\.pdb$/.pdb$1/' *.pdb   # actually rename the files
```

The command `rename` can be installed via

```
sudo apt install rename
```

Answer (score 11):

Using Perl `rename`:

```
rename -n 's/(\.\d+)(\.pdb)/$2$1/' *.pdb
```

Quick explanation:

- `*.pdb` Match all files that end with `.pdb`. (Done by the shell)
- `(\.\d+)` Match a literal dot, then one or more decimal digits. The parens create a match group.
- `$2$1` Reverse the first and second match groups.
- `-n` No action (simulate). If the output looks good, run the command again without this flag.

Comment: LOL. Same thought. You were 48 seconds quicker.

Comment: @PerlDuck Lol, yeah, same thought. The answers complement quite well too: you cover installation, I cover syntax.

Answer (score 11):

Through [`mmv`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/mmv.1.html) (rename multiple files by wildcard patterns) it's mush easy:

```
mmv '*.*.*' '#1.#3.#2' *.pdb
```

or `zmv` of `zsh` shell; it's a module that allows to do rename; see [ZMV-Examples](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/zsh-lovers.1.html):

```
zmv -w '*.*.*' '$1.$3.$2' *.pdb
```

Comment: Both `mmv` and `zmv` seem rather exotic to me. Do you mind elaborating a bit what they are and what they do?

Comment: I added a links to their manpage and examples.

Comment: `mmv` is pretty cool. Seems better-suited to this kind of renaming than `rename`, albeit being less flexible in terms of name matching.

Answer (score 8):

You can use this script:

```
for i in `seq 1 2000`; do
mv file.$i.pdb file.pdb.$i
done
```

Or this copy-paste friendly command:

```
for i in `seq 1 2000`; do mv file.$i.pdb file.pdb.$i; done
```

For use above commands, put all 2000 files in one folder and then open terminal in that directory, then run above command in it.

Answer (score 5):

Recently nautilus, the default file manager, received a batch rename dialog. It is not yet powerful enough to do what you want. But luckily there is thunar, an alternative file manager that can be installed. With thunars rename dialog you can do what you want using the GUI.

First install thunar:

```
sudo apt install thunar
```

Start thunar, navigate to the directory that has your files. Then select all of them. Press <kbd>F2</kbd>.

In the dialog that opens, again, select all files. Change mode to "Search & Replace" and to "Name & Suffix". Check "Regular Expression". Now use the following as search and replace patterns:

```
file\.(.+)\.pdb
```

and

```
file.pdb.$1
```

Finally click the rename button.

The advantage of this way is that you get a visual preview of what will happen before you actually do the renaming.

[image: thunar rename dialog]

Comment: You can make most programs print English messages by prefixing the command with `LC_MESSAGES=POSIX`, e. g. `LC_MESSAGES=POSIX free`. Works the same for graphical applications although in the case of persistent applications like Nautilus in its default configuration you need to terminate the previous instance with `nautilus -q` first.

Comment: @DavidFoerster thanks for mentioning, image replaced.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `rename` from `util-linux` for this (the command is called `rename.ul` in ubuntu):

```
rename.ul .pdb '' *
rename.ul "file." "file.pdb." *
```

This first removes the `.pdb` extension from the end and then re-inserts it into the middle.

Comment: Pretty cool. I wasn't aware of `rename.ul`. The syntax is a bit, um, unexpected, but it actually works the way you advertise. Plus: it also has a `-n` (don't touch, just tell) switch.