# Need a graphical renaming tool which can rename files recursively

Tags: software-recommendation, batch-rename

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What mass file renaming tools are available?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/10607/what-mass-file-renaming-tools-are-available)

ATM I am forced to use freeware in Windows to rename SOME Linux data files. Linux also creates files like "Filename.ext" as being different to "filename.ext", and !@#$hg".ext ... which cannot be recognized by Windows.

"pyrenamer" ... mentioned in another answer cannot auto-rename more than the one immediate folder.
I use Ubuntu, not ARCH linux, because I am not CLI.  Despite some answers here (designed by and for CLI programmers), how can Ubuntu GUI (not CLI) do file renaming?

BTY: in ONE folder only, THUNAR is far better than silly pyrenamer.  But Thunar cannot auto-rename recursively.

Comment: @January In my opinion the questions isn't a duplicate. This question has specific requirement, it is not a generic question looking for a file renaming tool