# changing file names in a directory

Tags: software-recommendation, files, batch-rename

Can I change the name of all the files in a directory automatically?  For example, I want to remove all the spaces in some tex files.

I don't want to spend days going file by file and editing the name.

Comment: Please check this question http://askubuntu.com/questions/10607/what-mass-file-renaming-tools-are-available It is the same as yours and answers are already giving you several options for the tool you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks the command line prompt was what I was looking for.  Make this an answer so I can accepted it.