# Easier way to rename batch files Like Windows

Tags: batch-rename

Ok Im finding all the rename options on this site and around the entire internet a hassle I  for one would like to rename batch files like in windows where I put in the name and it renames all files such as

Example -
*picture

picture (1)

picture (2)*

in windows all you do is **highlight all the files you want to rename** and right click and rename them. like in the example I want to name the files "picture" and then **windows will rename them that with the numbering beside them**.
could such a feature exist without the major tools and command lines

Comment: It is not clear what exactly you are asking for. Could you please put a few examples? Yes, there is an example in your post, but I fail to understand what you are asking for. And please remember, not all of us have exposure to Windows.

Comment: I think it shouldn't be too hard to write a bash (or python) script for this.

Comment: I hope because such a feature does not exist in ubuntu alone and I believe it should. that way Im not renaming everything one at a time

Answer (score 1):

Just searched around and it looks like there's a program to do that called 'GPRename'

> GPRename is a complete batch renamer for files and directorys. GPRename easily can replace, remove, insert, delete and number consecutively files and directorys.

It seems to be able to do what you want.

There doesn't seem to be a way to do this in default Ubuntu, though.

([source](https://askubuntu.com/a/10611/176889))

Comment: ive tried it and its not easy to use the fact that I cant find a simple program to rename files as windows would is a heartache. no program is just for casual use it takes know how.

Comment: @Zetchzie you can try some of the other programs in the source link. Please put some effort into learning it