# Mass renaming files with special format

Tags: batch-rename

I want to rename several hundred files whose names are formatted as follows:

```
A Study in Scarlet - Arthur Conan Doyle.mobi
Anvil of Stars - Greg Bear.mobi
City and the Stars, The - Arthur C. Clarke.mobi
```

After renaming I want to reach this naming scheme:

```
Arthur Conan Doyle - A Study in Scarlett.mobi
Greg Bear - Avil of Stars.mobi
Arthur C. Clarke - City and the Stars, The.mobi
```

A bonus would be to remove all irregular characters from the name, as there are:

1. `_` [underscores] to replace by blank
2. `%20` to replace by blank
3. `[]` to replace with rounded ones `()`

Comment: For ways to accomplish this with a GUI, see http://askubuntu.com/questions/511862/an-ubuntu-linux-alternative-of-bulk-rename-utility-for-windows

Comment: ^ also http://askubuntu.com/questions/10607/what-mass-file-renaming-tools-are-available

Answer (score 3):

I wrote a small bash script to do the job.

```
#!/bin/bash

# Variables
extension='mobi'
report='report.log'    

if [ -f $report ];
then
    rm -rf $report
fi

echo $'renaming files . . .\n'

for filename in *.$extension
do
    temp=$(echo $filename | tr '_' ' ' | tr '%20' ' ' | tr '[]' '()' | tr -s ' ' | sed 's/\.[^.]*$//' )

    part1=$(echo $temp | cut -f1 -d-)
    part2=$(echo $temp | cut -f2 -d-)
    new_filename=$(echo "${part2#?} - ${part1%?}.$extension")
    echo $(mv -v "$filename" "$new_filename") | tee -a $report
    if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
        echo $'\n\nScript FAILED'
        exit 1
    fi
done

echo $'\n\nScript SUCCESSFUL'
exit 0
```

Create a .bsh file inside the directory in which your .mobi files are stored and paste the above code :

Open a Terminal with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> and navigate to the directory in which your script is stored :

```
cd /path/to/directory/
```

To change the permissions of the script :

```
chmod +x <filename>.bsh
```

To execute the script :

```
bash <filename>.bsh
```

If for some reason the `mv` fails you will receive an error `'Script FAILED'`, otherwise you'll get `'Script SUCCESSFUL'`.

---

### Explanation

`tr '_' ' '` replace underscores with whitespace

`tr '%20' ' '` replace `%20` with whitespace

`tr '[]' '()'` replace square brackets with parentheses

`tr -s ' '` replace multiple spaces with one

`sed 's/\.[^.]*$//'` extracts only the name of the file without the extension

`${string#?}` remove first character of a string

`${string%?}` remove last character of a string

`mv -v` this will show in the terminal which files are being moved. `-v` stands for verbose.

`tee -a changelog.log` By default `tee` command reads from standard input, and writes to standard output and files. `-a` stands for append.

`if [ $? -ne 0 ]` checks if the previous command was successful.

`report.log` stores the previous and latest name of each file.

---

**Note**

The script assumes that the filename contains only one dash `-`

Comment: Nice script! Have you tested it, and will you add the bonus features?

Comment: @andy256 Script updated to cover the additional features

Answer (score 0):

You could use `find`, `xargs`, and `prename` to do this. Read their `man` pages.

`prename` applies a Perl "regular expression" to file names, and `find` and `xargs` are used to deal with filenames containing <kbd>Space</kbd> characters.

I can offer:

```
find . -type f -iname '*.mobi' -print0 | \
    xargs -0 prename -v -n 's%^(.*/)(.*)( - )(.*)\.mobi%$1$4$3$2.mobi%'
```

And, it worked for me:

```
  $ find . -maxdepth 1 -name '*.mobi' -print0 | xargs -0 prename -n -v 's%^(.*/)(.*)( - )(.*)\.mobi%$1$4$3$2.mobi%' 
./A Study in Scarlet - Arthur Conan Doyle.mobi renamed as ./Arthur Conan Doyle - A Study in Scarlet.mobi
```

You could use additional executions of `prename` to change your other funny characters. Be sure to read `man perlre` to learn about Perl Regular Expressions. If you haven't used regular expressions before, a quick-start introduction is available in `man perlrequick`, and a longer tutorial introduction is available in `man perlretut`.