# GUI batch renamer for Linux

Tags: software-recommendation, files

Need a batch renamer app for Linux.

I have 4 folders with 3 folders each. after the rename operation, I want to have

```
folder1
  - file1.txt
  - file2.txt
  - file3.txt
folder2
  - file1.txt
  - file2.txt
  - file3.txt
and so on.
```

When I try to use Krename => [$dirname]####, I get

```
folder1
  - file1.txt
  - file2.txt
  - file3.txt
folder2
  - file4.txt
  - file5.txt
  - file6.txt
and so on.
```

Any suggestion for a GUI app that can do it? Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [An Ubuntu/Linux alternative of Bulk Rename Utility for Windows?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/511862/an-ubuntu-linux-alternative-of-bulk-rename-utility-for-windows). Also see [How can I rename many files at once?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/10607/how-can-i-rename-many-files-at-once)